# Is there a way to use a recordset or column of data from Excel in a SQL query in a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Is there a way to use a recordset in a SQL query in a join? I have a column of data in Excel that I am currently looping through to get data with a SQL query. It would be great if I could use my excel column in a query to get all the data at once.

I have a table of data from one query in Excel and I would like to use the IDs in Excel to do another query in another database on a different server. Right now I am looping through the list, but that is very time consuming. It would be much faster if I could read in the list of IDs and include them in one query.

The data from my first query gets:

```
  Site Name    Site ID   Pump ID    Pump Type    Meter ID    Site Health
  Abby         101       12b4ga7    HU1042C      83hagd6     Good
  Betty        312       734jdg2    HU1042C      19347xh     WARNING
```

What I would like is to be able to read the list of Pump and Meter IDs from Excel and us them in a join for a SQL query to get the Pump & Meter performance data that is located in a different server.

It would be difficult to make a single query because each one now is already big and messy. Also by using the excel data it would allow the user to add additional site and pump data.

Is it possible to do that in VBA using ADO?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a temp table? You could import your excel as a .csv to this temp table, and use that temp table in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following, note that the file location is on the server:

```
--Excel 2007-2010
SELECT * --INTO #productlist
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\temp\product.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [ProductList$]');

--Excel 97-2003
SELECT * --INTO #sitelist
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
    'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\temp\product.xls',
    'select * from [ProductList$]');
```

Comment: Would I have to save a temp file or could I copy it from my current workbook?